# Did a yacht owned by a Polish company with Ukrainian owners travel from Rostock to Christiansø on September 6-7, 2022?

Tags: europe, germany, ukraine, organized-crime

A number of mainstream German newspapers [claimed](https://www.zeit.de/politik/ausland/2023-03/nordstream-2-ukraine-anschlag) on March 7 that a likely Ukrainian commando travelling on false passports boarded a yacht registered to a Polish company (but ultimately owned by Ukranians) from the German port of Rostock on September 6, and used it to travel to the vicinity of the island of Christiansø next day. It's also claimed (apparently based on leaked intel from the investigation) that traces of explosives were found on this yacht.

> Konkret ist es den Ermittlern nach Informationen von ARD-Hauptstadtstudio, Kontraste, des SWR und der ZEIT gelungen, das Boot zu identifizieren, das mutmaßlich für die Geheimoperation verwendet wurde. Es soll sich um eine Jacht handeln, die von einer Firma mit Sitz in Polen angemietet worden sei, die offenbar zwei Ukrainern gehört. Die Geheimoperation auf See soll den Ermittlungen zufolge von einem Team aus sechs Personen durchgeführt worden sein. Es soll sich um fünf Männer und eine Frau gehandelt haben. Demnach bestand die Gruppe aus einem Kapitän, zwei Tauchern, zwei Tauchassistenten und einer Ärztin, die den Sprengstoff zu den Tatorten transportiert und dort platziert haben sollen. Die Nationalität der Täter ist offenbar unklar. Die Attentäter nutzten professionell gefälschte Reisepässe, die unter anderem für die Anmietung des Bootes eingesetzt worden sein sollen.
>
> Das Kommando soll den Ermittlungen zufolge am 6. September 2022 von Rostock aus in See gestochen sein. Die Ausrüstung für die Geheimoperation sei vorher mit einem Lieferwagen in den Hafen transportiert worden, heißt es. Im weiteren Verlauf ist es den Ermittlern den Recherchen zufolge gelungen, das Boot am folgenden Tag erneut in Wieck (Darß) und später an der dänischen Insel Christiansø, nordöstlich von Bornholm, zu lokalisieren. Die Jacht sei dem Eigentümer im Anschluss in ungereinigtem Zustand zurückgegeben worden. Auf dem Tisch in der Kabine haben die Ermittler den Recherchen zufolge Spuren von Sprengstoff nachweisen können. Nach Informationen von ARD-Hauptstadtstudio, Kontraste, des SWR und der ZEIT soll ein westlicher Geheimdienst bereits im Herbst, also kurz nach der Zerstörung, einen Hinweis an europäische Partnerdienste übermittelt haben, wonach ein ukrainisches Kommando für die Zerstörung verantwortlich sei. Danach soll es weitere geheimdienstliche Hinweise gegeben haben, die darauf hindeuteten, dass eine proukrainische Gruppe verantwortlich sein könnte.

Probably the most faithful translation, albeit in paraphrase from [The Local](https://www.thelocal.dk/20230308/nord-stream-sabotage-linked-to-ukrainian-owned-yacht/):

> According to the report, a group of five men and one woman rented the yacht from a Polish-based company with Ukrainian owners. The group all used false passports and their true nationalities are unknown.
>
> Traces of explosives have been found on the yacht, which set sail from the German city of Rostock on September 6th, 20 days before the explosions, which destroyed the two pipelines at a point off the coast of Sweden and just south of the Danish island of Bornholm.
>
> “The traces lead in the direction of Ukraine,” Die Zeit wrote in its article. “However, investigators have not yet found any evidence as to who ordered the destruction.”
>
> The newspaper said that, “according to its information”, a western intelligence service had already tipped off its European partners in the autumn that a Ukrainian commando unit had been responsible for the attack, after which there had been “further intelligence indications that a pro-Ukrainian group” was behind the attack.

Basically, since the rest of the details probably can't be verified independently for now, can the movements of this yacht be verified with open-source intel?

Comment: If they were on such a mission I doubt they had a transponder, so I would rule out the possibility of open source intel. Probably they didn't even carry mobile phones so I would also exclude that the intelligence tracked cell locations. But the area is busy and there are a lot of ships and patrols that could have carried some cameras. But intelligence through private/police cameras recording would be difficult to verify.

Comment: Can you translate the quote?

Comment: @FluidCode: and footage is public, at least at  the port entry https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nt5XjWuv0KM

Comment: Anyhow, intersteting thread here https://twitter.com/AricToler/status/1633205268824686593 Apparently a Bavaria cruiser 50 operated by Mola company might be the ship involved. Nobody (incl. the harbormaster) saw any yachts pull into Wieck on the 7th, so that bit might be wrong. But this type of ship is too small to be required to have AIS. And apparently Die Ziet mistook Wieck for Wiek.

Comment: OTOH some Danish researchers are compiling SAR data for the area, so we might be surprised https://ing.dk/artikel/dtu-hunts-jammers-and-dark-ships-near-nord-stream-263738 But I don't know if the resolution is enough to spot a 15m yacht, and those satellites might not pass often enough. It's said to have 20m resolution, https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-1-sar/overview so it's going to be 1 pixel at best.